# Best way to get an entire row, where a certain column = certain value?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I would like to query an entire row of data where a certain column equals to a certain value.

```
chain1 = row_filters.RowFilterChain(
    filters=[
        row_filters.ColumnQualifierRegexFilter("VOLTAGE SCREW CONVEYOR DRIVE"),
        row_filters.ValueRangeFilter(b"0.693", b"1")
    ]
)
```

Here is my filter, but this only gets the 1 cell. I want to get the entire row. Anyone got any master tips on how to make that happen?

I managed to make it happen with two calls to Bigtable, but I don't think it is efficient at all.

```
chain1 = row_filters.RowFilterChain(
    filters=[
        row_filters.ColumnQualifierRegexFilter("VOLTAGE SCREW CONVEYOR DRIVE"),
        row_filters.ValueRangeFilter(b"0.693", b"1"),
        row_filters.StripValueTransformerFilter(True)
    ]
)

rows = table.read_rows(row_set=row_set, 
                        filter_=chain1)

# Get the rowkeys
rowkeys = [row.row_key for row in rows]

# Get the rows for these rowkeys
row_set = RowSet()
for rk in rowkeys:
    row_set.add_row_key(rk)

# Final soln
rows = table.read_rows(row_set=row_set)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [conditional row filter](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigtable/latest/row-filters.html#google.cloud.bigtable.row_filters.ConditionalRowFilter) which lets you combine a *base filter* with a *true filter* and a *false filter*. The true filter is used if the base filter emits any cells, otherwise the false filter is used. Following your example, it would be something like

```
condition = RowFilterChain(
    filters=[
        ColumnQualifierRegexFilter("VOLTAGE SCREW CONVEYOR DRIVE"),
        ValueRangeFilter(b"0.693", b"1"),
        CellsPerRow(1), // since we only need one cell to trigger the true filter
    ]
)

conditionalFilter = row_filters.ConditionalRowFilter(
    base_filter = condition,
    true_filter = PassAllFilter(), // this way you get the whole row and not just the single cell value
    false_filter = BlockAllFilter()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get all columns from read_rows with column filter.
See doc for read_rows():

filter (RowFilter) – (Optional) The filter to apply to the contents of the specified row(s). If unset, reads every column in each row.

https://googleapis.dev/python/bigtable/latest/table.html

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is likely to model your table around this problem. BT isn't designed for data model flexibility - its not SQL. For quick, efficient reads, don't rely on conditionals within the rows. You should consider either adding that value in the row-key OR generating a dedicated table where all the data meets your condition (thus eliminating the conditionals). Using filters can hurt performance).

to quote google:
The conditions filter, in particular, can increase latency, because conditions are much slower than other filters. If your read request is extremely performance-sensitive, do not use conditions in the request. (see https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/filters)